# Correlated Sql Query is not giving the desired output

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SqlLite. My table consists of `jobno`'s and the time (`ondate`) on which it was created. I want to select the most **recent jobno from each groups**.

The `ondate` is not in the standard date form. It contains values in this format `09/08/2013 04:04:30`  So I have done ordering of `ondate` little differently.

```
select r1.jobno, r1.ondate 
from reports r1 
where(
     select r2.jobno 
     from reports r2 
     where r1.jobno=r2.jobno 
     ORDER BY 
           substr(r2.ondate,7,4)||
           substr(r2.ondate,1,2)||
           substr(r2.ondate,4,2)||
           substr(r2.ondate,11) desc
    ) 
group by r1.jobno <=1
```

The ordering by `ondate` is correct. It gets ordered properly.
The correlated Query is wrong it is not giving me the correct output. Can anyone please help me correcting this query.

Comment: Maybe: group by r1.jobno <= 1

Comment: I tried it. That is not the issue. I made an edit in the question regarding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select r1.jobno, r1.ondate 
from reports r1
where
    r1.ondate = (
        select ondate
        from reports as r2 where r2.jobno = r1.jobno
        order by
           substr(r2.ondate,7,4)||
           substr(r2.ondate,1,2)||
           substr(r2.ondate,4,2)||
           substr(r2.ondate,11) desc
        limit 1 
    )
```

Comment: Thanks once again sir :-) It is working...!! I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @coding no problem, actually I'm not sqlite guru, more SQL Server and postgreSQL, but'll try to help if possible :)